# ADFIND show "Description","Title", "Phone", "Fax" , after show all members in a AD Group

Tags: active-directory, membership

I have used ADFIND -f "&(objectcategory=group)(cn=AccessIntraCX)" member to show all members,

but I would like to show addtional details, for each members, such as Title, Description, Phone, FAX. how can i do it ? 
Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

AdFind.exe -b OU=???,DC=???,DC=???-f "objectcategory=person" name description displayname useraccountControl -nodn -csv

You can put any field you want